# Trying to understand IntelliJ's project structure with modules

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm playing around trying to learn spring (MVC), and I find that I don't fully understand how the project is setup in IntelliJ.

When I built the project after setting it up, I noticed that in the /out folder the exploded war didn't have all the necessary files like the Web-Inf folder etc.  I did finally get it deployed locally with tomcat, but I want to understand things a little better.

So I have a Module which is an exploded war.

In the project settings, I see my 'appname' and it has a sub-item which says 'Web'.

In the module, under the 'add content root' I have the root path to my project.
I then have 'source folders' which points to my /src/main/java folder.

My project is laid out like:

```
/src/main/java/... (this has my controllers, entities, services etc.)
/src/main/web/ (this has my WEB-INF etc.)
```

In the 'Web' item, I pointed my 'web resource directories' to my /src/main/web:

1. should this point to my WEB-INFO folder?

I have screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I guess both my war and exploded war modules should have the exact same content?

Why do I have to specify my source path?  Is that basically telling IntelliJ to compile these files, and the web resource path is for files that just have to be copied to the output folder, and the compiled classes to go there also?

Is a module similiar to what you call a project in a vs.net solution?  i.e. you can open it independently of the entire solution?

Comment: FWIW, the standard Maven webapp directory is src/main/webapp. I can't recommend sticking to the defaults enough. Also, in general, IntelliJ should be configured to use the default Maven output directories.

Comment: You'd also generally have a src/main/resources for things like XML and property files; most of those files belong on the classpath. See the [Maven directory structure docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your app is a maven project with a valid pom file then you can just open the pom.xml as the project and intellij will automatically set up the project correctly.
You can try to mvn archetype:generate a sample project and open it.